# Asp.Net Core - upload file to database with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file, send it to the controller with ajax and save it in the database. Without Ajax, it is working perfectly, but when I submit the code with ajax in the controller I get a 0 result and cannot save the files into the DB.

Here is my code:
View:

```
<form method="post" id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="UploadFile">
      
                <div class="k-content">
                    @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                    .Name("files")
                    .Multiple(true)
                    .Messages(m=>m.Select("Select"))
                    .Validation(validation => validation
                    .AllowedExtensions(new string [] { ".doc", ".docx", ".pdf", ".txt"})
                    .MaxFileSize(5242880)
                    )
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { aria_label = "files"})

                    )
                    <p style="padding-top: 1em; text-align: right">
                        <button type="submit" id="uploadfile" class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded-pill">Upload</button>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
```

The ajax call:

```
        $("#uploadfile").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var fileUpload = $("#addfile").data("kendoUpload"),
            files = fileUpload.getFiles();

        var filedata = new FormData();
        
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            filedata.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("UploadFile")',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: filedata,
            success: function (message) {
                alert(message);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            },
        });

    });
```

And the controller, which works fine without ajax, but when data is submitted with Ajax, I get 0 result for the `filedata`

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IEnumerable<IFormFile> filedata)
    {
        foreach (var f in filedata)
        {
            if (f != null)
        {
            if (f.Length > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(f.FileName);
                var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

                var objfiles = new FileUpload
                {
                    FileName = fileName,
                    FileType = fileExtension,
                    FileSize = f.Length,
                    CretedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
                };
                using (var target = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    f.CopyTo(target);
                    objfiles.FileData = target.ToArray();
                }
                _context.FileUploads.Add(objfiles);
            }
        }
            else
            {
                return Ok(false);
            }
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok(true);
   }
```

Comment: I hope the following blog will help you to upload the file using Ajax Jquery. The file will only be uploaded to the wwwroot folder. From there, you need to upload it to the database https://codemurals.blogspot.com/2020/08/upload-file-in-aspnet-core-mvc-using.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `rawFile`, as it holds the actual file data. And the key name should be corresponding to the receive parameter.

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    filedata.append("filedata", files[i].rawFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**the simple compelete solution for this is following**

**js code**

```
 var fileupload = $("#FileUpload").get(0);
    var files = fileupload.files;
    var formData = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        formData.append('files', files[i]);
    }
```

****controller use IFormFile instead of IEnumerable****

```
public IActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile files)
{
    **for storing in your project folder**
    string filePath = "";
    if (files != null) {
        string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
        filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, files.FileName);
        using(var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                files.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```